# Cannot create controller with Entity framework - Unable to retrieve metadata for ' '

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a noob to ASP.net and have no idea why the controller isnt being created, in the tutorial by me copying it from word to word it worked fine allowing me to create a database.

Following the structure of this tutorial but in my own way (just changing a few names)-http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-model

**Charity.cs :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CharityWebsite.Models
{
    public class Charity

    {
        public String DisplayName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Double Amount { get; set; }
        public Double TaxBonus { get; set; }
        public String Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public class CharityDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Charity> Donations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Web.Config:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-CharityWebsite-20160221090932.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-CharityWebsite-20160221090932;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="CharityDBContext"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Donations.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Error :**

> 'Unable to retrieve meta data for CharityWebsite.Models.Charity' 
>   CharityWebsite.Models.Charity has no key defined. Define the key for
>   this entityType. Donations:EntityType:EntitySet 'Donations' is based
>   on type 'Charity' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Your model does not have a primary key. Try adding an Id field.

Comment: My days, It worked thanks!

Comment: Also any idea how I can open text file read and display contents? would I have to create a seperate form for that?

Comment: You could use File.ReadAllText() to read all the contents of the file, in the controller and then passed them to the view.

Comment: Thanks bro, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Solve the issue try adding a primary key into the model.

```
[Key]
[Required]        
public long ID{ get; set; }
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Btw - C# does not have a bigint type - maybe you mean long or BigInteger

Comment: @Teodor Thanks for correcting, i have edited the code.