# Unable to retrieve metadata when controller create

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create controller with vies for entity framework. As model class I'm going to use Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

And like data context class this:

```
public class RetroGadgetEntities:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error when trying to create controller "Unable to retrieve metadata for 'RetroGadget.Models.Product'".
As I understand it is actualy thrown when code generator trying to create strongly typed view, but I can't figure out why.

**UPD:**
Here is my Web.config.

```
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="RetroGadgetCon" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=RetroGadget.Models.RetroGadgetEntities;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>   
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

**UPD2**

```
public class Product
{   
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ManufacturerId")]
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

Why this error thrown and what I can do with it?

Comment: Are you trying to use Code First by scaffolding model class to a controller? Can you provide web.config contents to be analyzed for possible errors?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto add it to UPD section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'v solved it.
The actual problem was with linked classes.

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Manufacturer
{
    [Key]
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Problem was that there was no field Products in Manufacturer class. So I'v changed this like this.

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    [Key]
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are possible fixes you can do:

**1)** If you're using Code First & error message indicates *Entity 'X' has no key defined* or *EntitySet 'X' is based on type 'Y' that has no keys defined*, add primary key attribute (`KeyAttribute`) to model class property which serves as identity column:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Product
{
    [Key] // add this attribute
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

Additionally, ensure that `DbContext` constructor contains reference to named connection string in web.config:

```
public class RetroGadgetEntities : DbContext
{
    public RetroGadgetEntities() : base("RetroGadgetCon")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards, ensure all foreign keys & table relationships are arranged well (add `ForeignKeyAttribute` & `ICollection` if required).

**2)** If error message indicates *Unrecognized element 'providers'*, this `provider` section in web.config possibly causing metadata problem on EF context when creating controller from a model (often occurs when you're downgrading default EF version used by template to previous one):

```
<providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Try removing that `provider` part so that the `entityFramework` section becomes this:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

NB: The connection string section seems used invalid database location namespace as `RetroGadget.Models.RetroGadgetEntities`, try changing `Initial Catalog` to use a database name instead:

```
<add name="RetroGadgetCon" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=(database name);Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

If the connection still not working with given LocalDB instance, add `AttachDbFilename="(database path)\(database name).mdf"` & use `Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0` (depending on LocalDB version, see [SQL Server connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/)).

References:

[Cannot create controller with Entity framework - Unable to retrieve metadata for ' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542363/cannot-create-controller-with-entity-framework-unable-to-retrieve-metadata-for)

[Entity Framework: Unrecognized element 'providers' exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859153/entity-framework-unrecognized-element-providers-exception)

Comment: Thanks, but nothing works. 'RetroGadget.Models.RetroGadgetEntities' is actual db name(created by EF). And also I shuld mention that error message don't indicates anything, just 'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'RetroGadget.Models.Product' and nothing more.

Comment: I'm not sure if the error doesn't contain anything after "Unable to provide metadata for X". Can you provide additional details and/or screenshot from the error? Also your `Product` class has no data annotations defined, possibly the error comes from it.

Comment: What datails do you need? I can provide a screenshot but it is in russian. But there is nothing more on it, just error text I'v provided.

Comment: @Gleb Usually any error message has exception details & stack trace related with it. Check system/application event log to see the detailed info for the error, I think just providing primary key attribute will fine in similar issues.

Comment: I'v added attributes, you can see that in UPD2. But there is the same error. Also I haven't find visual studio(or its components) errors in application event log.